# Replace alt tag if its not empty

Tags: php, regex, replace, alt

I have a regex condition which replace image alt tags if they're empty.

```
// <img src="test1.jpg" alt="">

$replacement = '$1HELLO$2';
$pattern ='~(<img.*? alt=")("[^>]*>)~i';
$content = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $content);

// output <img src="test1.jpg" alt="HELLO">
```

I'm trying to find a way if alt tag is not empty then it should replace the whole string. I have tried this but it will add word in the beginning instead of replacing.

```
// <img src="test2.jpg" alt="my alternative text">

$replacement = '$1HELLO$2';
$pattern ='~(<img.*? alt=")(.+/S.+>)~i';
$content = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $content);

// output <img src="test2.jpg" alt="HELLOmy alternative text">
```

While i want output to be `<img src="test2.jpg" alt="HELLO">`

Edit: I tried with DOM Parser method earlier but there was few issues. This is the code.

```
function replaceALT($content) {
    global $post;
    $post = get_post($post->ID);
    $content = $post->post_content;
    $alt_keyword = "HELLO";
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadHTML($content);

    $images = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');

    foreach ( $images as $image) {
        if (empty($image->getAttribute("alt"))) {

            $image->setAttribute('alt', $alt_keyword);

        }
    }

    $content = $dom->saveHTML();

    return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'replaceALT');
```

There was few issues. It was modifying post content for some reason. `<p>` tag was removed and replaced with `<br>`. Which i solved by using `return wpautop( $content );`. Other issue is that `img` custom data was removed. For example, WordPress TwentySeventeen theme return image like this in a post.

```
<img src="http://localhost/wp/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/image-1356510220.jpg" alt="" width="3264" height="2448" class="alignleft size-full wp-image-24" srcset="http://localhost/wp/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/image-1356510220.jpg 3264w, http://localhost/wp/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/image-1356510220-300x225.jpg 300w, http://localhost/wp/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/image-1356510220-768x576.jpg 768w, http://localhost/wp/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/image-1356510220-1024x768.jpg 1024w" sizes="(max-width: 767px) 89vw, (max-width: 1000px) 54vw, (max-width: 1071px) 543px, 580px" />
```

But DOM parser return image like this.

```
<img src="http://localhost/wp/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/image-1356510220.jpg" alt="HELLO" width="3264" height="2448" class="alignleft size-full wp-image-24">
```

And as i needed to replace alt tag inside post content div.

```
<!-- default output -->
<div class="entry-content">
    <p><img src="http://localhost/wp/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/image-1356510220.jpg" alt="" width="3264" height="2448" class="alignleft size-full wp-image-24" srcset="http://localhost/wp/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/image-1356510220.jpg 3264w, http://localhost/wp/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/image-1356510220-300x225.jpg 300w, http://localhost/wp/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/image-1356510220-768x576.jpg 768w, http://localhost/wp/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/image-1356510220-1024x768.jpg 1024w" sizes="(max-width: 767px) 89vw, (max-width: 1000px) 54vw, (max-width: 1071px) 543px, 580px" />Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
</div><!-- .entry-content -->
```

It was returning output like this.

```
<!-- DOM parser output -->
<div class="entry-content">
<p><!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd"><br />
<html><body><img src="http://localhost/wp/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/image-1356510220.jpg" alt="HELLO" width="3264" height="2448" class="alignleft size-full wp-image-24">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</body></html></p>
</div><!-- .entry-content -->
```

Can someone help me with this. Thanks

Comment: By all means, DOM based solution will be clearer, but you may replace `)(` with `)[^"]*(` in your original pattern.

Comment: Thanks a lot. As i need both conditions separate, so i used it in my second example. `$pattern2 ='~(<img.*? alt=")[^"]*(.+/S.+>)~i';` It works. Do you think its good or it can be improved to find existing alt tag and replace it.

Comment: Of course it must be improved. Use a DOM parser.

Comment: I tried with dom parser earlier but there was few issues. Please check code here: https://pastebin.com/UJJR84ct
As i needed to replace alt tag inside content div. It was returning output like this in middle of a page `<div class="content"><DOCTYPE><html><body>CONTENT</body></html></div>` Also for some reason WordPress the_content filter was removing all `<p>` tags. Which i solved using `wpautop()`. Can you help me creating a dom parser func which search inside a div using $content variable and replace alt tags. You can also mention earlier regex comment. I will choose it as an answer. Thanks

Comment: Please add the DOM code you have been using so far, to the question itself I will check then what can be done.

Comment: See https://3v4l.org/Yjm0s

Comment: I just added DOM code in question and issues i have with that. Can you please take a look now. Thanks

Comment: Have you seen `$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$dom->loadHTML($content, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);`?

Comment: Just tried and it solved `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd"><br /><html><body>` issue. Thanks. 
Any idea why its removing `srcset=` and `sizes`attribute? When i use regex function. That works fine and `return $content;` just like default output.

Comment: There is an issue with `$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8'); $dom->loadHTML($content, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);` Its returning a single image. All text is gone and if i add more images. They don't show up as well.

Comment: Add this line before DOM code: `libxml_use_internal_errors(true);`. Does it solve all the issues?

Comment: I added that line but same issue.. Its returning single image. Also that single image doesn't have srcset and sizes. I tried to run it here. https://3v4l.org/DvE4U output is empty.

Comment: [It does not remove anything](https://3v4l.org/TTRmF).

Comment: That is really strange. I wonder why wordpress is causing issue. I have tested with all default themes and they are returning only first image. I'm trying it in functions.php file. The issue is LIBXML addition in dom. Please take a look at screenshots. Preview with LIBXML_HTML: http://prntscr.com/ktgh9t  Preview with $dom->loadHTML($content): http://prntscr.com/ktgiah

Comment: I can only suggest [handling the issues manually](http://php.net/manual/en/function.libxml-use-internal-errors.php#refsect1-function.libxml-use-internal-errors-examples) or use [`Simple HTML DOM parser`](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: I tried with simple html dom parser. Single image issue is solved but its still modifying code. `srcset` and `sizes` attributes are still not working. It seems like WordPress issue with DOM parsing. And for some reason, `$image->setAttribute` is not working with simple html dom parser. Here is the code. https://pastebin.com/d43SvejD

Comment: Ok, I see WP is a buggy thing. So, `'~(<img\s(?:[^<]*?\s)?alt=")[^"]*("[^<]*?>)~i'` works, right?

Comment: Yes. That one works and replace alt tag whether its empty or not. But as i need both conditions separately. So i used this regex if alt is not empty `~(<img.*? alt=")[^"]*(.+/S.+>)~i` It works on first image, not all. Any idea? Thanks for all the help. Really appreciate it.

Comment: If it is not empty, you need `+`, not `*`. Try `'~(<img\s(?:[^<]*?\s)?alt=")[^"]+("[^<]*?>)~i'`, it must be safer.

Comment: Done... I just added up vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the best solution here is

```
'~(<img\s(?:[^<]*?\s)?alt=")[^"]+("[^<]*?>)~i'
```

**Details**

- `(<img\s(?:[^<]*?\s)?alt=")`  - Group 1:

  - `<img` - a literal substring
  - `\s` - a whitespace
  - `(?:[^<]*?\s)?` - an optional substring of 0+ chars other than `<` as few as possible followed with a whitespace
  - `alt="` - a literal substring
- `[^"]+` - 1 or more chars other than `"`
- `("[^<]*?>)` - Group 2:

  - `"` - a `"`
  - `[^<]*?`  - any 0+ chars other than `<` as few as possible
  - `>`  - a `>` char.